# AVSpeechSynthesizer is not letting View Controller Deallocate

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a view controller and in the .h I have:

```
{
    NSString* textToSpeak;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVSpeechSynthesizer*  synthesizer;
```

In the .m of my view controller, I am using the synthesizer to play and pause a pre made script I created.

For example:

```
-(void)userProfileData:(UserProfileData *)userProfileData didReceiveDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{

    NSDictionary* resultsDict = [dict valueForKey:@"result"];
    textToSpeak = [resultsDict objectForKey:@"text"];

    UIBarButtonItem* pauseItem = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0];
    [pauseItem setEnabled:YES];


    [self startSpeaking];
}


-(void)startSpeaking
{
    if (!self.synthesizer) {
        self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
        self.synthesizer.delegate = self;
    }

    [self speakNextUtterance];
}


-(void)speakNextUtterance
{
    AVSpeechUtterance* nextUtterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:textToSpeak];
    nextUtterance.rate = 0.25f;

    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:nextUtterance];
}
```

Before I created this synthesizer, I would navigate back to the parent view controller and dealloc would be called (I have a log statement in it to make sure it is called). However, as soon as I added this synthesizer, the dealloc is no longer being called. I am wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it. Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `textToSpeak` and where do you set it?

Comment: I create textToSpeak in .h using -> NSString* textToSpeak;    I then fill it with the desired text like this in a method -> NSDictionary* resultsDict = [dict valueForKey:@"result"];
    textToSpeak = [resultsDict objectForKey:@"text"];

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I have updated as you requested

Comment: The only reason that I can think of is that you are trying to deallocate the view controller while the synthesizer is still in the process of speaking `nextUtterance`.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam NO, I am running [self.synthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.. @ChrisLoonam you were a great help in the end. I just needed to stop the synthesizer beforehand and everything was deallocated properly